# Does original DB change when the linked DB changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-web-api, data-binding, visual-studio-2019

I have two different projects sharing same SQLite database(One is Web-api, Other one is WPF App). However, the database is located in (let's say project A). In the project B, I used "Add as link" to copy the DB to project B.

I have three questions

1. If the DB in project A changes, the linked DB also changes. However, if  i change the DB in project B, does the original DB change?
2. Is there any better way to do this?
3. Will it still work if i release the solution.

[original DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs6Ky.png)

[copied DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uplyx.png)

[properties of copied DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIXtG.png)

Comment: Open your project folders in explorer side by side and look at them.. How many db files are actually on disk in all of this? Also search the entire folder structure your projects are in for *.sqlite and find them all; file based databases may get copied to other places (bin folders) during a build. This can often cause serious confusion about which db to change (as a developer) and which db is altered by the program (saving records)

Comment: why not just try out what happens when you change one?

Comment: well of course i did try to change it but i got an exception in my code. I assume that the exception was thrown because of changing the linked DB doesn't change the original one(I add stuffs to the linked DB and then retrieve it at another section). Thanks for replying :)

Comment: @CaiusJard in the WPF application folder there are two .sqlite folders and i think that is correct. the one in the bin folder is updated when i debug my app, and the linked one is updated when the original one changes. My question is can i change the linked db and the original one still changes? is there any better way of doing this (as a file database). Thanks for replying.

Comment: The reason I asked what I did about the number of files is because: with a project that has a fgile based DB, that DB will show in the solution explorer as being alongside e.g. the CSPROJ file.. It's copied to the bin/debug (or release) folder when the project runs becaus ethe app needs to find it, not in the CSPROJ folder, but alongside the EXE in the debug folder. The setting for that is found by clicking the db in the solution explorer and looking at "Copy To Output Folder" -> always/ifnewer/never.

Comment: Separately to this if you have some other project and you've got the DB showing in that solution exploder then it either got there because the db file was copied out of the other project and into this one, in which case they are two separate files on disk with the same name.. OR.. it got there because this solution explorer is simply showing a file that exists elsewhere on disk outside of this project's folder structure, in which case there is only one copy of the file (though it might get copied to this projects's bin folder). If there is one file, editing either is editing the one file

Comment: And this was why I asked you to double check how many files *you actually have on disk* regardless of how many files you see represented in solution explorer. Solution explorer is NOT exactly a file/folder explorer/viewer. It doesn't always directly represent the files and folders on disk unless you run it in file/folder view mode. Mostly it is full of things that are not files, like methods and properties, or it is showing files hierarchically that aren't hierarchically stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A local database like a sqllite file should be installed to appdata.

This is user specific by default, but there's also a public user you could use.

It's up to your installer - and that means you - to put it there.

If this file is to be shared by two apps.

You would need to configure whatever you're using as an installer to write to a common location in appdata. That should be under public if multiple users need to share the file.

By default, if you add a file as content and copy if newer that will end up in your bin when you develop and it will work for you. When you install, if you install to program files the sdf will end up in there as well and your user will not be able to write to it.

There's a more complete explanation of appdata files here:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30915.c-local-files.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your concern! While i was copying the DB, deep in my heart i knew it that it was wrong way of doing it. I will do as you said. Thanks

Comment: i've tried to put my db to appdata, but i've come across a problem. I tried creating my db at appdata/local/isolatedstorage but when i do the same for the other project, it creates a seperate file in different subdirectory. Could you please help with this one?